# Javascript scroll event fired without scrolling on reload on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using latest FF (same happens on safari i noticed), and my scroll event is firing multiple times, instead of when i actually scroll:

```
var newsPanel = $('.newspanel');

newsPanel.on('scroll', function(e) {
  console.log("SCROLL FIRED"); //Fires multiple times on page reload
  ...code
}
```

Any idea why is this happening and how to fix it? It's working fine on Chrome.

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: This is jquery, don't get confused.

Comment: It most likely fires when the scrollbar was not at the initial position at the time the reload was done. Because after the reload the browser will jump to the last scroll position. And if individual elements change their height while loading, then the scroll event might fire additional times.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remember the last reported scroll position and check it against each new reported scroll position, if the values are equal you ignore it, if they are different you run your logic and update the last position

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed this by adding `initialLoading` boolean and running scroll logic only when `initialLoading` is false. Might not be the best solution but it works for me.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you. where/when do you set your flag to false, might I ask?